# Laravel 4 Passing exception variables

Tags: php, laravel, scope

I'm confused by the error that is being received while attempting to throw an exception, `Undefined variable: validation`

This is the first time I've tried to create a custom exception and I must be doing something wrong. Here I'm just trying to validate a row being inserted into the database (which works), the problem I'm having is with the exception.

Controller

```
public function store()
{
    try
    {
        $this->deals->insertDeal(Input::all());
    }

    catch(ValidationError $e)
    {
        return Redirect::route('deals.create')
        ->withInput()
//this is the unknown variable
        ->withErrors($validation->errors);
    }

    return Redirect::route('deals.create')
            ->with('message', 'Deal Created');
}
```

Model

```
public function insertDeal($input)
{
    $validation = new Services\Validators\Deal;

    if ($validation->passes()) {

        $deals = Deals::create($input);
    }

    $errors = $validation->errors;
    throw new ValidationError($validation->errors);
}
```

Custom Validation Error

```
class ValidationError extends Exception {}

App::error(function(ValidationError $e){

});
```

To recap, i'm just not sure why i'm getting the error of undefined variable when I try to trigger the exception. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `$validation` is not available within the scope of the `store()` method.  You can pass the errors through the exception by rewriting your `ValidationError` class:

```
class ValidationError extends Exception
{
     protected $errors;

     public function __construct($errors)
     {
         $this->errors = $errors;
     }

     public function getErrors()
     {
         return $this->errors;
     }
}
```

and accessing the errors in `store()`:

```
public function store()
{
    try {
        $this->deals->insertDeal(Input::all());
    } catch(ValidationError $e) {
        return Redirect::route('deals.create')
          ->withInput()
          ->withErrors($e->getErrors());
    }

    return Redirect::route('deals.create')
            ->with('message', 'Deal Created');
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. I haven't made an exception class so I was confused about what should go inside of it. This helped clear it up, thanks again